# PHP firebase push notification not displayed on screen and sound not playing if app is in background

Tags: php, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using this class and php code to send push notification to android device but notification is not displayed on screen even if the app is in front. Sound isn't playing if the app is in the background

```
class PushNotifications
{

private static $URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

private static $API_ACCESS_KEY = 'AAAAr....fpmYmt';

public function __construct()
{

}

public static function sendPushNotification($token = "", $fields = array())
{
    $registrationIds = array();

    array_push($registrationIds, $token);

    $msg = array('body' => $fields['body'], 'title' => $fields['title'], "priority" => $fields['priority']);

    $fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIds, 'notification' => $msg);

    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . self::$API_ACCESS_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json');

    #Send Reponse To FireBase Server
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, self::$URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
}


require_once 'PushNotifications.php';
$device_token    =  "d3j....O9kj";
$fields          =  ["title" => "message title", "body" => "message text", "sound" => "default", 'priority' => 'high'];
$response        =  PushNotifications::sendPushNotification($device_token, $fields);
echo $response.'<br>';
$array = json_decode($response, true);
```

How to fix this to make the notification get displayed on screen and to play the sound? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any hints please

Comment: try passing android_channel_id